# if-else statement in bison

Tags: if-statement, bison, shift-reduce

I'm trying to do the if-then statement in bison. The problem is that im working on a solution that everyone says that is working, but it doesnt :( my code is:

statement : matchedstmt
    | unmatchedstmt
    ;
matchedstmt : if '(' expression ')' matchedstmt else matchedstmt

```
| otherstmt                 
;
```

unmatchedstmt : if '(' expression ')' statement

```
| if '('expression ')' matchedstmt else unmatchedstmt   
;
```

otherstmt :  expressionstmt

```
| compoundstmt  

| iterationstmt     

| returnstmt    
;
```

...

where "if" & "else" are %token

!! in terminal it says that i have one shift/reduce.

I also tried %nonassoc and %left

what can i do??

Comment: What makes you think the problem is in that part of the grammar, exactly? And please format your code using the `{}` button.

Comment: @rici That's because i have deleted that part of my grammar and terminal compiled my code successfully. Sorry for my bad format of my code thats beacuse im a new user

Comment: I know that you are a new user, and I understand that it is not always obvious how to format code. But it's not difficult. You can edit your own question even with minimum reputation, and it will take only a few second to correctly format the code: select the code and hit the `{}` button. While you've got the edit control open, take a few minutes to read the editing help (see the `?` icon).

Answer (score 0):

The following can be processed by bison with no conflicts of any kind:

```
statement : matchedstmt     
    | unmatchedstmt                 
    ;
matchedstmt : if '(' expression ')' matchedstmt else matchedstmt 
    | otherstmt                 
    ;
unmatchedstmt : if '(' expression ')' statement 
    | if '('expression ')' matchedstmt else unmatchedstmt   
    ;
otherstmt :  expressionstmt 
    | compoundstmt  
    | iterationstmt     
    | returnstmt    
    ;
```

That's unsurprising since you are using a standard mechanism for disambiguating the `if ... else` statement.

Presumably, the shift-reduce conflict is somewhere else in your grammar, possibly involving an interaction with this fragment. I suggest you add more statement types one at a time until you find the rule which causes the conflict. Unfortunately, LR grammars do not compose well: it is quite possible for two perfectly conflict-free fragments to produce a conflict when they are combined in a grammar.

Answer (score 0):

the best way for solve this problem using `%nonassoc`.

```
%nonassoc THEN

%nonassoc ELSE

%%


statement:              TIF TLPAREN expression TRPAREN TTHEN statement %prec THEN

                        | TIF TLPAREN expression TRPAREN TTHEN statement TELSE statement


%%
```